# Dell xps i7 plug into screen?

Tags: dell-inspiron

I am studying architecture and have a Dell XPS i7 and a Dell screen, which I have connected with a DVI cable from screen into an adaptor to HDMI port on my laptop. I want to work on my screen independently of my laptop display. I.e. to be able to drag photos from a file on my laptop display into Photoshop on my screens display or work on Achicad while having a movie playing on my separate screen?

Is this possible? Do I need to change a setting because at the moment both the laptop and screen are displaying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. Yay, you've got what you want!

Proper detailed answer: Use <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to select "Extend", and your Windows desktop will be extended onto your second monitor. Then, right-click on your desktop, hit "screen resolution" to go to display settings* (or go through the control panel), and arrange them as you have them physically set up so you can drag windows between them.

*Windows, I don't understand you.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks for the Windows key icon :)

Comment: [Credit where credit is due](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6048/is-there-a-kbd-for-the-windows-key) ;p.